# Compare RMSE between original and logged time series data

Tags: logistic, forecasting, data-transformation, model-comparison

I have some time series data, both in the original form $y$ and in logged form $\log(y)$. I should compare the models generated by applying neural networks and find the best one.

How to decide which one is better since the two values are in different units?
Would it be useful to normalize the RMSEs over the standard deviation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ultimately interested in $y$ (rather than $\log(y))$, then I would suggest transforming the fitted values of $\log(y)$ back to the original scale and calculating RMSE for them. (Note that simple exponentiation may or may not be a good idea; see Dave Giles' blog post ["More on Prediction From Log-Linear Regressions"](http://davegiles.blogspot.ca/2014/12/s.html) and paper by Bårdsen & Lütkepohl ["Forecasting levels of log variables in vector autoregressions"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207011000112) (2011).) That should be directly comparable with the RMSE from the other model where the dependent variable is $y$.