# Log transformed MAE to original value

Tags: forecasting, error, accuracy

In order to evaluate the forecast accuracy of a model I'm using a step wise cross validation to get a MAE value and use that again to calculate the MASE.

As part of the model specification the data is logged and differenced (diff = 1).

**My question is:**

How can I convert the MAE from a logged difference to a number in the original format (in this case Mn USD)?

The MAE's I get are between 0.041 and 0.078, hence simply taking the exponential  returns a very small range of average errors when looked at in light of its original value.

```
exp(0.041) = 1.041852
exp(0.078) = 1.081123
```

Assuming that this is in fact the wrong way to go about it (the results sure seem strange), what is the correct way of going about it?

The answer in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205370/compare-rmse-between-original-and-logged-time-series-data) question suggests that the transformation needs to be done before calculating the MAE (or RMSE in the example), but given the fact that it's based on the output of a cross validation where the model is run several times, I suspect that might skew the results.

**CV code and MAE calculation for reference:**

```
library("forecast")
library("vars")

d <- log(abs(rnorm(75)))
x <- log(abs(rnorm(75)))

d.d1 = diff(d, differences = 1)
d.x2 = diff(x, differences = 1)

dx <- cbind(d.d1,d.x2)
dx <- as.ts(dx)

# Forecast Accuracy
j = 12  #Forecast horizon
k = nrow(dx)-j #length of minimum training set

predicted <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:j, function(i){

  trainingset <- window(dx, end = k+i-1)

  fit         <- VAR(trainingset, p = 1)                       
  fcast       <- forecast(fit, h = j-i+1)
  `length<-`(fcast$mean$d.d1, j)
}))

actual <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:j, function(i){

  actual      <- window(dx[,1], start = k+i, end = k+j)
  `length<-`(actual, j)
}))

# Calculate MASE
MAE <- mean(rowMeans(abs(actual-predicted), na.rm = TRUE))
MAE

abs.scaled.err <- abs(rowMeans(actual-predicted, na.rm = TRUE)/MAE)
as.data.frame(abs.scaled.err)
MASE <- mean(abs.scaled.err)
MASE
```

Comment: Normal procedure is to calculate errors on the original scale, i.e., after back-transforming your forecasts (exponentiating and cumulating, the back-transformations of logging and differencing). Could you explain in what sense you suspect that this might "skew" the results?

Comment: @StephanKolassa by skewing the results I admittedly misunderstood and assumed that the back-transformation were to happen prior to the fitting of the model (silly me). However, referring to the code above, calculating MAE as: 'mean(rowMeans(abs(exp(actual-predicted)), na.rm = TRUE))' appears to give results with very little variance and a subsequent MASE value of more or less exactly 1 regardless of model, which is why I found it strange. Precisely at what stage does the back-transformation need to occur?

Comment: You would back-transform the forecasts to the original scale, then compare them with the holdout actuals (also on the original scale, of course). I don't even see where you logged and differenced your training data. Please edit your question to include a *minimal* and *reproducible* example.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you, will do as soon as I get back to a computer!

Comment: @StephanKolassa please see the code, now edited to be replicable. I still feel that the results I get when doing `exp(actual)` and `exp(predicted)` are off when using my actual data, so seeing an example of how it's to be done properly would be of great help!

Comment: I don't see where you take logs of original data. And to be honest, I'm not overly keen on walking though 39 lines of code. Can you cut it down radically to about five lines, focusing on your core problem, and explain what you mean by "I feel my results are off"?